# Druid that is by default in beast form?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, homebrew, druid

So I'm a fairly new DM but I try really hard to figure out some way for my players to create and play the characters that they want.  One of my players really has his heart set on being a druid who is more comfortable in his wolf form (because the character was raised by wolves).  Needless to say he was quite disappointed to learn that he could only be a wolf for 4 hours a day at level 4.

Is there a rules supplement covering such a Druid?  If not, how would this be homebrewed?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] to get the best use out of the site.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I had a character like this in a previous game. The player had a lot of fun playing up his character's frustration about not being able to stay in beast form by default, so you might want to chat with your player about interesting RP opportunities here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1.  Is there a rules supplement covering such a Druid (one who prefers to stay in animal form)?**

No.  As of the current material published, there isn't a supplement for Druids published for the 5th edition DnD.  (Unlike previous editions, Wizards of the Coast hasn't published such source books yet.  Whether or not they intend to remains to be seen).

**2.  Does this need to be homebrewed?  Maybe not.**

The rules (p. 66, PHB) allow the Druid to don Wild Shape twice per short or long rest, and *recover expended uses* during a rest.  At 4th level, he can be a wolf for a bit longer than he thinks. :-)

2 hours per use times two uses per rest yields the following:

- If your party takes 1, 2, or 3 short rests per adventure day, and your Druid recovers during the long rest from the previous night, your Druid can use this ability 2, 4, 6, or 8 times per day at fourth level.  That means up to 4, 8, 12, or 16 hours per day in Wolf form.  If the Druid sleeps for about 8 hours during the long rest, that  can leave him in wolf form for most of the day, and longer as he progresses. (At level 20, his Archdruid class ability lets him Wild Shape as many times a day as he'd like, stay in beast form for up to 10 hours each time).
- Does this use of the RAW help, or will that conflict with the pace of your adventuring day, or other party issues?
- Note: time in wolf form will be reduced if he has to revert during a fight.
- The game was designed with 2-3 short rests, and 6 - 9 encounters (not all of which are necessarily combat encounters)per adventure day.

---

**3. How would this be homebrewed?**

Wizards of the Coast has some suggestions at the DnD section of their site [on the things to consider when modifying a class](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/modifying-classes).  The key considerations in the 5e DMG (Ch. 8) are:

1. Will it improve the game?
2. Will the players like it?

The other question you have to answer yourself if you make a modification is:

3. Will this change the power or balance of this class compared to the others?

There are some mechanical benefits to Wild Shape that go beyond the story/role play your player desires.  These include:

- The additional Hit Points pool that the transition to and from beast shape represents
- The improved Perception depending upon which form your Druid takes (Wolf?  Advantage on hearing and smell Perception checks)
- Speed.  (40 compared to human 30, for example).
- How arduous your adventure day is.
- In wolf form, the Druid can't speak .. how does this influence group or party play?  It could either be an obstacle or enrich game play through some interesting "role play as a canine" simulation.  The whole table might need to get on board with this so that it's a good fit for the whole group.

The ability to alter at will is, as noted, a 20th level class ability.  From that capstone ability we can infer that the Druid's Wild Shape options grow with the Druid as the Druid gains levels.  This is a class design feature, some of it being game mechanics based on various efforts to balance skills between classes.  (I realize that your PC isn't asking for the level 20 "at will" class ability).

When you try to vary this for your campaign, consider how many encounters the party typically handles during an adventuring day.  You may find that in a level or two, you don't need to homebrew anything, per part 2 of this answer / skill resets on short rest.

Comment: First off thank you very much for the informative answer. You're right, I hadn't realized that he regained the uses during a short rest so its true that he will be able to stay a wolf for longer. That being said, he probably will still be bugged by the fact he has to actively turn into a wolf as opposed to default into wolf form. But i may be able to figure out a way to fit it his to character without changing any of the rules. Thank you

Comment: @TomSterkenburg The point you offered has been folded in.

Comment: @ArtaSoral With the amount of time allowed already in wolf form, choosing to homebrew for him being in a default wolf form will probably have little balance impact, but as I've not tried this I can't comment further.

Comment: @ArtaSoral Keep in mind it's a very very powerful feature, one that Wizards decided was only in the grasp of level 20 Druids. Think of Beorn from The Hobbit

Comment: @TomSterkenburg Drat, that's a very good point. I guess if i want to make this work I would need to figure out some downside to it.

Comment: @ArtaSoral Beasts cannot speak. At all (pretty sure). So this leaves half the role-playing out for him. You can use this to balance out the strength of it in combat against the weakness of it out of combat

Comment: `The ability to alter at will is, as noted, a 20th level class ability.`
But that in my opinion is not really what the asker is asking, nor would it be a good way to do it.

Just make the character default to wolf, and need to use "Wild Shape" to get into their human form.

Comment: As an additional suggestion, you could limit his wild shape to only allowing changes between wolf and human forms (no bears, snakes, lions etc). Allow him to upgrade to a more powerful wolf at the same levels he'd usually be able to wild shape into them.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski I added that at the request of another comment, and am aware that the PC isn't asking for a 20th level ability.   I have added another sentence to point out that the Druid's wild shape ability grows with the Druid.

Comment: Firstly, a Druid is a Druid because of his affinity with nature. It is the nature of all beings to start small and work toward their goals. That said, let's say the player were to default to animal form. That would mean the reverse state becomes the secondary form. The player would only be able to be human for a limited time. Also, regarding HP and skills requiring the human form, they would not be accessible as an animal. If the animal were brought to 0 hp, then it would be knocked out and not reverted to human form. The human form however would revert to animal form when brought to Zero HP.

Comment: @EScoce who was that comment for?  Is there something in my answer that you feel needs attention?

Comment: No, just saying that if the player wanted to reverse the time constraints and be limited to them, that the player may find its not ideal.